# Maximum and minimum value of trace of unistochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, trace, unitary-matrices, stochastic-matrices

Let $P$ be a unistochastic matrix, that is, there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $P_{ij}=|U_{ij}|^2$. What is the maximum and minimum value of $\mathrm{Tr}[P]$? I'm also interested in the existence of any other local minimum or maximum over the unistochastic matrices.

Comment: Suppose $P$ is $n\times n$. Then $0\le\sum_i|u_{ii}|^2\le\sum_i1=n$. The lower bound is attained, for instance, when $P$ is a permutation matrix for a cyclic shift; the upper bound is attained when $P=I_n$.

Comment: For real $U$, the stationarity equations are $u_{ji}u_{jj} = u_{ij}u_{ii}$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$.